# Cron jobs not working

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab

I am hosting my magento 2 shop at all-inkl and unfortunately I can only use a "cgi bridge" to call the cron.php via a web cron job.

I have built that bridge which looks like that:

```
<?php
exec("/bin/bash cron.php  2>&1", $out, $result);
echo "Returncode: " .$result ."<br>";
echo "Script:" ."<br>";
echo "<pre>"; print_r($out);
?>
```

my cron.php looks like that:

```
#~ MAGENTO START
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /www/htdocs/USER/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v Ran jobs by schedule >> /www/htdocs/USER/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /www/htdocs/USER/magento2/update/cron.php >> /www/htdocs/USER/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /www/htdocs/USER/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /www/htdocs/USER/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
#~ MAGENTO END
```

But if I open the bridge file via my browser, I get this error:

> Returncode: 127 Script: Array (
>       [0] => cron.php: line 2: /bin/grep: Permission denied
>
> ```
> [1] => cron.php: line 2: CHANGELOG.md: command not found
> [2] => cron.php: line 3: CHANGELOG.md: command not found
> [3] => cron.php: line 4: CHANGELOG.md: command not found
> ```
>
> )

I have no idea how to get those cron jobs running.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 cron are run via cli, you can configure the cron as below.

Note: Update paths as your current system.

```
    <?php
    $output = exec("/opt/lampp/bin/php -d memory_limit=2G  /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/2.2.4/bin/magento cron:run");
    echo "<pre>"; var_dump($output);
    ?>
```